# How to use methods/call from different methods in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program to convert the number of inches a user inputs into feet, yards, and miles. Below is my working code for this, however, I need to separate each conversion (feet/yards/miles) into different methods that will be called from the main. How can I achieve this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int feet = 12;
        int yards = 36;
        int miles = 63360;


        Console.WriteLine("How many inches would you like to convert?");
        int inches = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        double numOfFeet = (double)inches / feet;
        double numOfYards = (double)inches / yards;
        double numOfMiles = (double)inches / miles;

        Console.WriteLine(inches + " inches is equivalent to " + string.Format("{0:N2}", numOfFeet) + " feet, or " + string.Format("{0:N2}", numOfYards) + " yards, or " + string.Format("{0:N2}", numOfMiles) + " miles.");
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and struggled with.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951451/c-sharp-how-to-pass-unknown-value-variable-user-input-to-return-method/44951611) is kinda similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: HINT: `static double GetFeetFromInches (double inches)
  {
   int feet = 12;
   return (double)inches / feet;
  }`
Give it a try, I am sure you can solve it :)

Comment: If you have already found tutorials telling you how to do this but you are having a hard time understanding how to apply it you need to either find better sources of information or else ask us a specific question about a specific point of confusion. We can't recommend tutorials and explaining how one of the most basic points in a programming language works is a little too broad. If you can tell us what problems you are having specifically though then we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not do something like this?

Note abstraction of logic to a new method passing in only `Inches` each time and return a type of double.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many inches would you like to convert?");
        int inches = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        double numOfFeet = ConvertToFeet(inches);
        double numOfYards = ConvertToYards(inches);
        double numOfMiles = ConvertToMiles(inches);

        Console.WriteLine(inches + " inches is equivalent to " + string.Format("{0:N2}", numOfFeet) + " feet, or " + string.Format("{0:N2}", numOfYards) + " yards, or " + string.Format("{0:N2}", numOfMiles) + " miles.");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static double ConvertToMiles(int inches)
    {
        int miles = 63360;
        return inches / miles;
    }

    private static double ConvertToYards(int inches)
    {
        int yards = 36;
        return inches / yards;
    }

    private static double ConvertToFeet(double inches)
    {
        int feet = 12;
        return inches / feet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should something along the lines of:

```
static double ConvertInchesToFeet(double inches){
     //code for inches to feet
}

static double ConvertInchesToYards(double inches){
     //code for inches to Yards
}

static double ConvertInchesToMiles(double inches){
     //code for inches to Miles
}
```

And your main would simply call them like this:

```
double numOfFeet = ConvertInchesToFeet(inches);
double numOfYards = ConvertInchestToYards(inches);
double numOfMiles = ConvertInchestToMiles(inches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use static methods. They would look like this:

```
static double InchesToFeet(int inches)
{
    return (double)inches / 12;
}

static double InchesToYards(int inches)
{
    return (double)inches / 36;
}

static double InchesToMiles(int inches)
{
    return (double)inches / 63360;
}
```

To call them you just need to use a method call in your main like this:

```
double result = InchesToFeet(inches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you could accomplish this in a Console application:

- Create methods to do the calculation and write to the console from within the method.
- Create functions to return the answer and write to the console in the Main method.

When working with Console applications it's important to note that the class is a Static class. Therefore, you will need Static methods/functions if you are defining them within your console application.

Thus, option 1:

```
static void CalcuateFeet(int inches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inches as feet:" +  ((double)inches) / 12.0;
}
```

And option 2:

```
static double CalcuateFeet(int inches)
{
    return ((double)inches) / 12.0;
}
```